# VB.NET Serial Port reading HEX data and insert in the textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rfid

I want to read the data from UHF RFID reader that is connected on one of my com port, the data should be in HEX and must be a complete HEX that should be pasted in the textbox in my windows form application that I made in VB.NET.

Kindly help me I am new in VB.NET Programming.I need a vb.net code for this task:

My code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() 
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(s)
    Next s

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a port")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        SerialPort1.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared buffer As String = ""

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

    Try
        Dim rcv As String = _SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
        buffer = String.Concat(buffer, rcv)


        Dim hexVal As Integer
        hexVal = Convert.ToInt32(rcv, 16) '16 specifies the base

        txtReceived.Text = hexVal

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SerialPort1.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Nice homework. Unfortunately, we are not a coding service. Show us your try so far.

Comment: Am I right, you want to convert the buffer to ASCII-hex-codes?

Comment: I want to receive the hex instead of ascii but my code is not working may be there are faults in my code

Comment: Then, you will have to loop through the string (tip: `For Each c As Char in buffer` and then convert each char in ascii-code and convert the ascii-code in hex. Rather simple to do I think.

Comment: Basically, I want to read a HEX of RFID card and paste this HEX into the textbox.That's all...Although, it looks simple task but I am unable to do that in VB.NET

Comment: Doesnt't matter, that is the same way as I said.

Comment: What do you mean that you want to "read HEX"?  Hex is just a representation of an integer value for display purposes.  Is your RFID actually sending hex strings or is it bytes?  It seems like you should not be reading strings but bytes and then convert those bytes to hex representation.

Comment: data coming from RFID Reader is in ascii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem..

the line

```
hexVal = Convert.ToInt32(c, 16) '16 specifies the base
```

is trying to convert a character to int32, but the function is assuming that the incoming value is already hexadecimal and you're getting a completely wrong answer.

Incidentally, your data is 8 bit binary and your serial port reader reads each 8 bits as a char type.

What you need is to use the VB built in function `Hex`, which takes an integer/byte (in this case the ascii code of each character) and returns a hex value as a string so

```
Dim x As Integer = 15
Dim s As String = hex(x)
```

will assign "F" to the string

All well and good. However, If you want a 2 digit hex string, you'll need to check if the returned string is only one character and if it is, add a "0" to the beginning.

So, your lines

```
Dim hexVal As Integer
hexVal = Convert.ToInt32(rcv, 16) '16 specifies the base
txtReceived.Text = hexVal
```

should be replaced with ..

```
Dim hexVal As string =""
For Each c As Char In rcv
    hexVal = heval & AsciiCharToHexSring(c)
Next
txtReceived.Text = hexVal
```

and add this function to convert the character and add a "0" if necessary ..

```
Private Function AsciiCharToHexSring(s As Char) As String
    Dim hexdigit As String = Hex(Asc(s))
    If hexdigit.Length = 1 Then
        hexdigit = "0" & hexdigit
    End If
    Return hexdigit
End Function
```

If you don't need a 2 digit hex number every time, just delete the `If..End If` block

Comment: Now, 50% of my problem has been resolved.I am getting HEX in the textbox but there are more issues that I am facing. My code is given below:

Comment: Issues are listed below:

Comment: 1. SerialPort1.ReadLine is not reading any data from UHF RFID reader                                  
2. SerialPort1.ReadExisting() is reading data from UHF RFID reader but all the data is not coming in a single textbox, some of the bytes are appearing in1st textbox and remaining to the 2nd textbox                                                                              3. I made two textboxes -> one for USER RFID TAG ID & -> one for BOOK RFID TAG ID

Comment: 4. When user swipe first RFID card its complete hex should be inserted inside the first textbox having name "txtReceived1" & after that when user swipe another RFID card its complete hex should be inserted inside the 2nd textbox having name "txtReceived2" 5. Length of complete HEX of card is 21 bytes e.g. (CC FF FF 10 32 0D 01  E2 00 10  26 77 0D 01 51 23 30 23 55 2D), I want to read this complete 20 bytes in the textboxes for both User TAG ID & BOOK TAG ID in first textbox & 2nd textbox respectively

Comment: Second main issue that I am facing is some of the received bytes are altered(changed) especially first 3 bytes instead of receiving(CC FF FF) actually  received data is (3F 3F 3F), 8th byte is also altered every time instead of receiving (E2) my com port is receiving (3F) same is the case with 19th byte   so in short although data is receiving but some of its bytes are altered

Comment: plz help me, David Wilson

Comment: You should post these issues as separate questions with the relevant code in each question. Without code we have little hope of helping. Thanks

Comment: I already updated the code and also provided 2 images for you so that you can easily understand what i want to do

Comment: `Dim rcv As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine` ( this command is not working, not reading any data from the reader
                                                                                                                                     @DavidWilson

Comment: `Dim rcv As String = _SerialPort1.ReadExisting()` (this command is reading data but with some of the bytes altered & the complete 20 bytes is not coming in single textbox, some of the bytes goes to 2nd textbox ) @DavidWilson

Comment: Try
        Dim rcv As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine
      
        Dim rcv As String = _SerialPort1.ReadExisting()  
        buffer = String.Concat(buffer, rcv)
        Dim hexVal As String = ""
        For Each c As Char In rcv
            hexVal = hexVal & AsciiCharToHexSring(c)
        Next
        If txtReceived1.Text = "" Then
            txtReceived1.Text = hexVal
        ElseIf txtReceived2.Text = "" Then
            txtReceived2.Text = hexVal
        Else
            txtReceived1.Text = ""
            txtReceived2.Text = ""
        End If

Comment: Separate questions please . This isn't only for your benefit, but users searching for similar solutions for their own problems will not see any solutions to the extra problems you're having.

Comment: By the way. If an answer solves your original question, click the tick to the left of the answer and that user gets reputation points :-)

Comment: i tried to tick but it is showing an error that your post has been deleted

Comment: i am new at this form, sorry for that most of the rules I don't know

Comment: I am going to ask this question as a separate question, will wait for help from your side and this time I will not forget to tick.THANKS! in advance.

Comment: tick succeeded :)

Comment: posted another question at link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472571/serial-port-reading-hex-data-and-insert-in-the-separate-textboxes-book-rfid-hex0

Comment: According to your saying, I post this into another new question and also gave you tick but there is no more response from your side! Kindly respond to my question ASAP, THANKS! @DavidWilson

Comment: Apologies if I have caused offence. General conversation is frowned upon as this doesn't help other users reading those comments. I never said that I would be able to answer your questions. Only that you should post them as a new question. Sadly I don't know enough about serial ports to be certain of an answer to your new question - Oh and saying things like "Kindly respond ASAP" is likely to annoy people - not me today though :) It is best to treat comments as if the people talking are two business professionals. I'll have another look at your new question to see if I can get any ideas.