# Serial Port reading HEX data and insert in the separate textboxes (Book RFID Hex & User RFID Hex)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, serial-port, rfid

GUI of Project

[[image: (image 1)]]

In this image I am using **UHF reader's software** for testing of RFID cards so **my end result in the textboxes should be unique 12-byte HEX of RFID card**
[[image: (image 2)]][(image 2 preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnDlZ.png)

Basically, I am working on Library Management System(LMS) project & I am trying to issue books by using the **User identity** (***User RFID Tag ID in HEX***) and **Book identity**(***Book RFID Tag ID in HEX***). When user will come in the library for issue a book then he/she will swipe his/her RFID card as a result user ID (12-bytes)in HEX will appear in the first textbox instantly and after that he/she will show book to the reader that the person wants to issue as a result Book Tag Id (12-bytes) in HEX will send to the second textbox instantly.
(**Output of reader is 20 bytes** as shown in **image 2**)

Now the problems I am facing are following:

1) I am not receiving 20 bytes of HEX in the single textbox by using the command (**_SerialPort1.ReadExisting()**) some of the bytes appear in first textbox and rest of the bytes appear in the second textbox, (**SerialPort1.ReadLine**) this command is reading noting so this command is not of my use

2) The second issue that I am facing is that some of the bytes that are appearing in textboxes are altered(changed) e.g (**CC FF FF 10 32 0D 01 E2 00 10 26 77 0D 01 51 23 30 23 55 2D**) these 20-bytes should be received but in actual first byte received is **3F**, second is **3F**,3rd is **3F** and 19th is **3F** and **one more byte with different HEX value**.

Kindly help me! My code is provided below:

```vb
Imports System                      
Imports System.IO.Ports              
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort1.PortName = "Com7"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()

    End Sub

    Private Shared buffer As String = ""

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

        Try

            'Dim rcv As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine
            'Dim rcv As String = SerialPort1.ReadByte
            Dim rcv As String = _SerialPort1.ReadExisting()  

            buffer = String.Concat(buffer, rcv)


            Dim hexVal As String = ""
            For Each c As Char In rcv
                hexVal = hexVal & AsciiCharToHexSring(c)
            Next

            If txtReceived1.Text = "" Then
                txtReceived1.Text = hexVal

            ElseIf txtReceived2.Text = "" Then
                txtReceived2.Text = hexVal

            Else
                txtReceived1.Text = ""
                txtReceived2.Text = ""
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Function AsciiCharToHexSring(s As Char) As String
        Dim hexdigit As String = Hex(Asc(s))
        If hexdigit.Length = 1 Then
            hexdigit = "0" & hexdigit
        End If
        Return hexdigit
    End Function


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()

        txtReceived1.Text = ""
        txtReceived2.Text = ""
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Kindly help me! @DavidWilson

Comment: Did you try Read method with byte array? You are reading binary data as string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, I didn't try because I don't know how to use this function.I am beginner in VB.Net.Can you update my code with this function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read data as byte array and convert that byte array values to hex string.

You can find reading example on this [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SerialPort-brief-Example-ac0d5004/sourcecode?fileId=47852&pathId=2004190332). See DataReceived event. It is something like that.

```
' Initialize a buffer to hold the received data 
Dim bufferArr(serialPort.ReadBufferSize) as Byte 

' There is no accurate method for checking how many bytes are read 
' unless you check the return from the Read method 
Dim bytesRead as Integer = serialPort.Read(bufferArr, 0, bufferArr.Length)
```

After reading you can convert byte values to hex string like that

```
Dim hexString as String = ""
For Each item as Byte In bufferArr
    hexString &= item.ToString("X2")
Next
```

Comment: kindly help me @DavidWilson

Comment: Sorry my bad. Sample code in C# and just converted it and updated my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: I tried but this command doesn't read any data `serialPort.Read(bufferArr, 0, bufferArr.Length)`